# Clarification On Exercise 7 of Chapter 6 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $(0, 1]$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[c, 1]$ for every $c > 0$. Define
> $$ \int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x $$
> if this limit exists (and is finite).
> (a) If $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0, 1]$, show that this definition of the integral agrees with the old one.

**Question(1)** I don’t understand the given definition. Like $f$ is defined on $(0,1]$, how can we talk about $\int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x$? Because by definition 6.1, $f$ needs to be defined on $[0,1]$. Do we have to assume $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0,1]$?

**Question(2)** I don’t know precisely what to prove. Can someone please tell, in term of If...then... format, what to prove?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132300/discussion-on-question-by-user264745-clarification-on-exercise-7-of-chapter-6-of).